# Concatenating Multiple Rows Into String

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, string-concatenation, stuff

I'm trying to concatenate multiple rows of a query into a string, but not getting the results I was expecting. The example that I'm working with should be returning one row, with the values of row 1 and row 2 concatenated in row 1 separated by commas. Instead, I'm getting two rows, with row 1 concatenated to itself and row 2 unchanged except for a comma in front.

Expected Result:

```
TYPEA, TYPE B
```

Actual Result:

```
,TYPEA,TYPEA
,TYPEB
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID,
                t.TicketNumber,
                tc.Description AS Code,
                (SELECT ',' + order_type 
                FROM Table_Order_Account oa
                WHERE oa.service_account = cs.CustomerServiceNumber
                FOR XML PATH ('')) AS Code3,
                oa.order_type AS Code2
FROM Table_Ticket t
WHERE (T.TicketType = 2 OR (t.tickettype = 1 AND tpc.Description = 'Records Update Needed'))
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Note: I'm working in SQL Server 2014, so STRING_AGG isn't an option for me.

Comment: Better upgrade your obsolete SQL Server version and use `STRING_AGG` rather than find a strange workaround for antiquated software

Comment: @JonasMetzler It's not quite obsolete yet. It has a whole four months of service life. 

Comment: As hinted in prior comments, SQL Server 2014 is scheduled for formal end of life in July. After this time it will no longer get updates... **not even critical security patches**. Seems like the best solution here is planning a migration project to a version that will continue to receive basic support, as that will also make the solution to this issue trivial

Comment: You'll have to add some sample data of table a and B as well as the whole query

Comment: Also, `b.account_number` is not a valid identifier based on what we can see. We need the full context.

Comment: Please read [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) then update your question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting extra rows is probably related to the outer query missing a `GROUP BY`. It only uses `DISTINCT`, but it includes `oa.order_type AS Code2`, so it's not going to reduce the rows further.

Instead, remove that column and the `LEFT JOIN Table_Order_Account as oa` completely, and use something like `GROUP BY t.ID, t.TicketNumber, tc.Description`.

You also need to knock off the leading comma. You can use the `STUFF` function to do that.

The third parameter of `STUFF` should be the length of the separator.

You should also use `.value` to unescape any possible XML characters.

```sql
STUFF(
  (
    SELECT ',' + order_type 
    FROM Table_Order_Account oa
    WHERE oa.service_account = cs.CustomerServiceNumber
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
  1, 1, '') AS Code3
```

And don't use `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications.

Comment: I edited the post and added the whole query, thank you for the comment!

Comment: @BLeahy you shouldn't include such a long query. You should cut out parts of your query to find the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem, and include example data that demonstrates the problem behaviour. Please read [ask], [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @BLeahy See new edit.